# onClick event is not working after I added an arrow function to invoke the function I was using

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am learning React and right now, I am trying to add an onClick event to my button that when clicked, it will display a joke that is being fetched from a Rest API.  I read the docs, and it says that for the onclick event to take place you need to call the function that you used, which in this case is componentDidMount. I initially used `{this.componentDidMount}`and I got the following error message: `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`. So I did some research and saw that I needed to use an arrow function so that it invokes componentDidMount.  I applied it and when I clicked the button, the joke does not change and when I checked the console, there  aren't any errors. Can somebody tell what could be going wrong and how to fix it?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class DadJokesApi extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            jokes: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'appliction/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState(prev => ({jokes: prev.jokes.concat(data)})))
    }

    render () {

        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.jokes.map(joke => 
                  <div key={joke.id}>
                     <p>{joke.joke}</p>
                     <button onClick={()=>this.componentDidMount}></button>
                  </div>    

                )}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default DadJokesApi;
```

Comment: ```componentDidMount``` is a life cycle hook name in react and that gets executed on mount of the ```DadJokesApi``` component..  and so don't use that name for your function.. Use some other name..

Comment: Dont use componentDidMount unless you want to fetch the jokes when the component is mounted. Also your onClick props should be `onClick={this.fetchJokes}` or whatever the function name you want to name it

Comment: I think you want it like this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-class-component-2j2qv .. Is it so??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few reasons why you are not getting expected result:

1. `componentDidMount` is a life cycle function. You cannot use it.
2. The reason for `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` is that you wouldn't have binded the event with `this` in `constructor`

There are few things that I updated in your code:

1. Create a separate function and not use life cycle function as a click event
2. Bind the function with `this` in constructor, so that the function has `this` as a context.

Check the [stackblitz sample of your working code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rf22j5).